# Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5 condition evolution behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode5, conditional-statements, xcode4.6

Following statement works in xcode 4.6 and if block is executed

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:FolderPath isDirectory:&isDirectory] && isDirectory)
```

But in xcode 5, it returned false and was going in else. After I had put both conditions in () it did work as expected. Actually it was silly mistake and that is how it should have been before as well, but somehow xcode 4.6 was giving true.

Correct statement : `if (!([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:FolderPath isDirectory:&isDirectory] && isDirectory))`

Any idea about why this behaviour difference in Xcode 4.6 and 5?

Comment: this is not related to Xcode (which is an IDE only) but the compiler used

Comment: did you switch from NON-ARC to ARC?

Comment: @Daij-Djan : Yes agreed .. .I was gonna change the title. And no, I did not switch from non ARC to ARC.

Comment: damn ;) that was my only idea....